# Magento multiple phtml contact form template

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, magento

I am creating multiple contact form and get ideas from http://www.milessebesta.com/web-design/magento-make-multiple-contact-us-forms-and-redirect-them-to-a-seperate-thank-you-pages/.

I created multiple contact forms that is to be used for a quick contact to several pages. One is a pop up form and other is another contact page. (PPC purpose)

I have prepared more than three .phtml contact form templates. These templates are almost the same but I added additional input forms.They are using the same email template and I use {{if}} {{else}} directives to get desired input values. I also created catalogs and add the static block that has the .phtml form.

I have www.mydomain.com/contacts that is working properly however the contact forms that are included in the static block doesn't send the form in this   `www.mydomain.com/catalog/another-contact-page`.

This is my form action and input hidden. based on the tutorial. i have to create an input hidden with a value of my desired url.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="custom_redirect" class="required-entry input-text field" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('custom_redirect') ?>" type="hidden" name="custom_redirect" value="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>catalog/another-contact-page">
```

I also put this peace of code on my controller

```
if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            if (isset($post['custom_redirect'])) { // If custom_redirect is set

                $redirect_url = $post['custom_redirect']; // Get the URL you want to redirect to

                $redirect_too = (explode(".com.au/", $redirect_url)); // Explode the Url

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));

                $this->_redirect($redirect_too[1]); // Redirect to everything everything after .com

                return;

            } else {

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            }
```

**PROBLEM:**

After modification I still can't send the contact us form. The post submission was stop somewhere in the browser and when try to refresh the page, it pop up's a warning **CONFIRM FORM RESUBMISSION**.

**QUESTION:**

What causes the problem? How can I use my custom phtml contact form to send inquiry email?

**UPDATE**

If you inspect the element, the form action value is missing even though I am using `action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

There may be PHP error at controller. 
You should try to debug code.
Make sure error reporting is turned on, write temporarily:

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the beginning of of index.php file.